# SLD REST Service

Tags: sld, geoserver-sld-service

My question is related to successful deployment of the SLD REST Service Community extension at the GeoServer REST APIs, and how to access related end-points.

After copying extension's JAR files to WEB-INF/lib (Tomcat servlet), seems like extension is not deployed. As stated at https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/sldservice/index.html - I should be able to access directory: /sldservice/ - but it does NOT exists !

Maybe, I've missed something at the installation procedure of this extension...?
I really need this service, where to access via end-points each particular SLD (e.g. to have a link to the SLD). Could You please provide some help?

Comment: did you restart GeoServer? if so what does the log file say? - if all you need is a link to the SLD then use `/rest/styles/` instead

Comment: Hi Ian! Yes, I've restarted GeoServer after deploying the jar-files at "lib/", but nothing happened. 
Regarding your suggestion to access styles via /rest/styles - actually I did succeeded to expose the style there, via SLD-editor, which creates two files - {SLD-name}.sld and {SLD-name}.xml -- with unique ID at <id>...</id> , thereafter it's available at /rest/sld .
Thanks for suggestion!

Nonetheless.. I've tried also: chown tomcat:tomcat *.sld ...nothing.
Also, it's useless on my opinion to create by my own the dir: /rest/sldservice -it must be dynamic created.

Cheers!